# three.js ObjLoader Memory Increasing

Tags: three.js

I am using OBJLoader.js. I have a button that on click removes a 3d model from scene and adds a new one but everytime the model is loaded, memory usage in chrome is increasing by about 50 MB and it is not reducing. I have tried "dispose()" and null, but not much of use. There is a animate function that is being called every second that renders the scene using renderer.

```
function freeMemory(model) {
if (model instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
    var texMat = model.material;
    texMat.map.dispose();
    texMat.map = null;
    texMat.dispose();
    texMat = null;
    model.geometry.dispose();
    model.geometry = null;
    model = null;
 }
}

function loadModel() {
scene.remove(model);
freeMemory(model);
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('test3d.obj', function(object) {
    object.children[0].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry = object.children[0].geometry;
    console.log(geometry);
    geometry.dynamic = true;
    var modelTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/tex_0.jpg");
    object.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material.map = modelTexture;
            model = child;
            model.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            model.translateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1).normalize(),
                    1.5);
            model.rotation.x = 0;
            model.rotation.y = 0;
            model.rotation.z = 0;
            modelInitialPositionX = model.position.x;
            modelInitialPositionY = model.position.y;
            modelInitialPositionZ = model.position.z;
            scene.add(model);
        }
    });
    modelTexture.dispose();
    modelTexture = null;
});
loader = null;
}
```

I there any best practice which i can use in adding and removing .obj and textures on button click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199591/1980846

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the animation, with the following code:

```
animate(){
    this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    this.render();
}
render(){
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}
stop(){
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the Object3D in a var before adding it to your Scene, you don't need to remove / dispose it and instantiate a new object, you can just modify it, and maybe this will not cause memory leaks.

try something like:

```
var model = new THREE.Mesh( firstGeometry, firstMaterial);
scene.add( model );
```

then, when you need to replace it, you just modify it:

```
model.geometry = newGeometry;
model.material = newMaterial;
```

without the need to add it again to your Scene.

if you fiddle it, I can edit your loadModel function.

Comment: another memory leak can be caused by you instantiating a new OBJLoader every time you have to load a model. That has no sense, because if you need to load multiple models, you just instantiate one loader, and use it every time you need

Answer (score -1):

a workaround is to try limiting the framerate.
i found it keep the ram usage to a minimum.
My sketch would keep using incremental ram until the pc would start to hang, sometimes the gpu usage was ~80%.

[Limiting framerate in Three.js to increase performance, requestAnimationFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285065/limiting-framerate-in-three-js-to-increase-performance-requestanimationframe)

Comment: Decreasing the framerate will not impact the memory used by loaded in models.

Comment: check stats panel after limiting framerate.